# Posting PHP Object Array with Ajax

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

Hi all I cant seem to work out what I'm doing wrong, I have an object array of files and trying to pass that array to be proccessed by another php file using ajax

my php object array is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Files Object
        (
            [id] => 39
            [case_id] => 35
            [file_name] => 5M UK Limited - Annual progress report 2017.pdf
            [file_path] => 5MUK01C/5M UK Limited - Annual progress report 2017.pdf
            [file_size] => 5233880
            [file_type] => application/pdf
            [file_date] => 2017-04-25 10:28:28
            [downloads] => 11
            [temp_path:Files:private] => 
            [upload_dir:protected] => /Users/johnfieldsend/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Web Development/document.center.new/httpdocs/uploads
            [upload_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => No Errors.
                    [1] => Larger then upload_max_filesize - Try to reduce the sizre of your file.
                    [2] => Larger than the MAX_FILE_SIZE - Try to reduce the sizre of your file.
                    [3] => Partial upload.
                    [4] => No file.
                    [6] => No template directory.
                    [7] => Can't write to disk
                    [8] => File type not allowed, please upload either a word or pdf file.
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Files Object
        (
            [id] => 40
            [case_id] => 35
            [file_name] => Notice to opt out 5M UK Limited.pdf
            [file_path] => 5MUK01C/Notice to opt out 5M UK Limited.pdf
            [file_size] => 182099
            [file_type] => application/pdf
            [file_date] => 2017-04-25 10:32:54
            [downloads] => 4
            [temp_path:Files:private] => 
            [upload_dir:protected] => /Users/johnfieldsend/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Web Development/document.center.new/httpdocs/uploads
            [upload_errors:protected] => Array
                (
                    [0] => No Errors.
                    [1] => Larger then upload_max_filesize - Try to reduce the sizre of your file.
                    [2] => Larger than the MAX_FILE_SIZE - Try to reduce the sizre of your file.
                    [3] => Partial upload.
                    [4] => No file.
                    [6] => No template directory.
                    [7] => Can't write to disk
                    [8] => File type not allowed, please upload either a word or pdf file.
                )

            [errors] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

this array is stored in a variable `$files`

Im trying to pass this to my `charts.php` file via ajax with the following code

```
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ajax/process/charts.php?chart=files',
      data: <?php echo json_encode($files, true) ?>,
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
    }).responseText;
```

if I inspect the page I can see the json string of my array being passed to ajax

```
type: 'POST',
  url: '/ajax/process/charts.php?chart=files',
  data: [{"id":"39","case_id":"35","file_name":"5M UK Limited - Annual progress report 2017.pdf","file_path":"5MUK01C\/5M UK Limited - Annual progress report 2017.pdf","file_size":"5233880","file_type":"application\/pdf","file_date":"2017-04-25 10:28:28","downloads":"11","errors":[]},{"id":"40","case_id":"35","file_name":"Notice to opt out 5M UK Limited.pdf","file_path":"5MUK01C\/Notice to opt out 5M UK Limited.pdf","file_size":"182099","file_type":"application\/pdf","file_date":"2017-04-25 10:32:54","downloads":"4","errors":[]}],
  dataType: "json",
  async: false
```

but I cant access any of this data in `charts.php`

My Response back is

```
array(1) {
  ["undefined"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Since you haven't shared charts.php code with us, it's difficult to troubleshoot. Your best tool is to use your browser's developer tools, specifically looking at "Network", and then choosing the "XHR" subtab.  Trigger your AJAX call, and see what's happening - does it post with a 200 / success response? If so, what is the information in the "response" sub-tab? What's the information in the "request" subtab?  Using that tool, you could then add something like `var_dump($_POST);` to your charts.php code, and start seeing what's happening in the "response" subtab when firing the AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be the following:

Maybe data is not defined properly in AJAX call properly, try the following:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ajax/process/charts.php?chart=files',
      data: { 
           "myArray": '<?php echo json_encode($files) ?>'
      }
      dataType: "json",
      async: false
}).responseText;
```

and try echoing it with (in charts.php):

```
echo json_decode($_POST['myArray']);
```

---

I had a similar problem 2 days ago, but my solution was different, I sent the array like this:

```
data { "myArray": '<?php echo urlencode(json_encode($myArray));?>' }
```

and fetched it like this:

```
json_decode(urldecode($_POST['myArray']));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Alen, yeah it was simply adding an identifier to my array then json_decode that post field